# How to generate incremental numbers in query, Access 2000?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to create query in Access 2000, but I want my first column to be generated sequence of incremental numbers, like 1, 2, 3, 4 etc... 
I plan to append this to a query so that I can then generate good report.

How can i do that, how should I use expression builder, some example of it?

Also some good tutorials on Expression Builder would be quite useful?

[image: query access 2000]

Comment: show your table structure and your attempts so far.

Comment: I added picture @Nathan_Sav

Comment: I will close the question, its just I don't know where to search for info.

Comment: `cint([tipprod])` would be a good start `cint([tpprod]) + DMAX()` would be another idea, so if max tipprod is 3, this would start at 4?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav the square brackets show an input window. I don't need input window.

Comment: see edit, it's a misspelt field name, so dome research on this to assist you, I wont do it so you can copy verbatim, you'll need to use this to further your own knowledge to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function which if for exactly the purpose. See in-line comments for typical usage:

```
Public Function RowCounter( _
  ByVal strKey As String, _
  ByVal booReset As Boolean, _
  Optional ByVal strGroupKey As String) _
  As Long

' Builds consecutive RowIDs in select, append or create query
' with the possibility of automatic reset.
' Optionally a grouping key can be passed to reset the row count
' for every group key.
'
' Usage (typical select query):
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) <> RowCounter("",True));
'
' Usage (with group key):
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False,CStr[GroupID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) <> RowCounter("",True));
'
' The Where statement resets the counter when the query is run
' and is needed for browsing a select query.
'
' Usage (typical append query, manual reset):
' 1. Reset counter manually:
'   Call RowCounter(vbNullString, False)
' 2. Run query:
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable;
'
' Usage (typical append query, automatic reset):
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter("",True)=0);
'
' 2002-04-13. Cactus Data ApS. CPH
' 2002-09-09. Str() sometimes fails. Replaced with CStr().
' 2005-10-21. Str(col.Count + 1) reduced to col.Count + 1.
' 2008-02-27. Optional group parameter added.
' 2010-08-04. Corrected that group key missed first row in group.

  Static col      As New Collection
  Static strGroup As String

  On Error GoTo Err_RowCounter

  If booReset = True Then
    Set col = Nothing
  ElseIf strGroup <> strGroupKey Then
    Set col = Nothing
    strGroup = strGroupKey
    col.Add 1, strKey
  Else
    col.Add col.Count + 1, strKey
  End If

  RowCounter = col(strKey)

Exit_RowCounter:
  Exit Function

Err_RowCounter:
  Select Case Err
    Case 457
      ' Key is present.
      Resume Next
    Case Else
      ' Some other error.
      Resume Exit_RowCounter
  End Select

End Function
```